# В чем разница между векторами и массивами?

Tags: c++

Всем привет! Начал изучение С++ и столкнулся с вопросом: в чем разница между векторами и массивами в С++?

Comment: Условно, вектор - это массив, размер которого может изменяться. А вообще, если изучаете, то об этом должно быть сказано в материалах.

Comment: *Какими* массивами? Если вы имеете в виду `int a[5]`, это одно, а если `std::array<int,5> a` — то это совсем другое...

Comment: Не знаю как именно в C++, но судя по другим языкам, с векторами должны быть доступны некие "векторные" операции, когда можно просто и, главное, быстро сложить два вектора, умножить вектор на скаляр и т.д. С массивами же обычно работают поэлементно, и таких специальных быстрых операций для работы с массивом как с целым у них нет.

Comment: Не стоит забывать, что в методичках и учебниках лохматых лет, int a[5] могли на голубом глазу обозвать "вектором"

Comment: @gbg Угу, раньше сплошь и рядом вектор - это одномерный массив, матрица - двумерный, а всё остальное - просто массив...

Comment: *столкнулся с вопросом: в чем разница между векторами и массивами* Открой конспект и посмотри, что по этому вопросу сказал на лекции преподаватель. Любое отклонение от **его** мнения скорее всего выйдет боком, особенно если на экзамене.

Comment: [Arrays vs Vectors: Introductory Similarities and Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15079462)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если отбросить все нестандартные определения и термины, то  массив является простейшим *составным типом*, пришедшим из языка Си. Массив объектов (включая фундаментальные типы) занимает неразрывную область памяти, его элементы являются подобъектами массива, его размер задается в момент создания. Размер массива выраженный в виде числа элементов является частью его типа.

```
int  arr[6]; // Переменная - массив int-ов размером 6

int* allocate(int size) 
{
    // dyn_arr присваивается значение указателя на массив заданного размера
    int  *dyn_arr = new int[size]; // выделяется динамически при исполнении
    return dyn_arr;  // возвращается указатель на первый элемент
}
```

Как таковой синтаксис языка Си++ не работает с понятием "вектор". Однако стандарт  на язык  описывает набор *стандартных компонент*, к таковым относится `std::array` и `std::vector`. Первый является структурой, ведущей себя как массив постоянного размера, за исключением того что она может быть возвращена из функции или передана без развоплощения в указатель на первый элемент. Второй является классом для работы с массивом в динамически выделенной области памяти, позволяющий уменьшать и увеличивать объем выделенной памяти по желанию, что требует перевыделения и копирования содержимого.